# How to write a regex to replace string like Street to St , Avenue to Ave etc in Teradata?

Tags: regex, teradata

I want to write a single regular expression to replace sub strings like Street to St or Tree to Tr inside of a specific string. Do I need to write separate regex expressions to to achieve that? I know in Teradata `OREPLACE` can be used but I am asking if there are any more proficient ways to do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions in Teradata](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Regular_Expr_Functions.085.10.html). However, they are most productive when you have concrete pattern that you need to match in *specific context* and eventually replace with some part of the input string.

In the following example, "Street" will be matched, but only the first capturing group will be taken for replacement:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Sherlock lives in Baker Street.', '(Str)eet', '$1', 1, 0, 'c');
```

If you have multiple search keywords and multiple replacements for them, you'd better use a 2-D ARRAY with the search and replace values in its dimension, and then use them in your code to perform search and replace.